# Who was Antwan's personality based on?

Tags: free-guy

In *Free Guy*, Antwan has a very over-the-top personality.

Was it based on anyone in real life? What inspired Antwan's personality?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zyRtfDzdWM is probably closer to the "over-the-top" you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be what you're looking for, but [Taika Waititi said that Antwan was based on an executive he worked with](https://www.looper.com/477536/the-surprising-games-the-free-guy-cast-would-want-to-live-in-the-most/):

> It turns out, a lack of original storytelling is part of where Taika Waititi's Antwan comes from. "I just thought it was funny, because early on, an executive, who I won't name, said, 'Okay, so this movie Free Guy, what's it based on?' And we were like, 'Nothing.' And the executive is like, 'Okay, you say nothing, but like, so it's not a sequel," director Shawn Levy explained in an interview with /Film. "Is it based on a comic book, graphic novel? What?' Like, 'No, no, nothing. New ideas.' Like, 'So it's a movie based on nothing?' I'm like, 'Yeah. Based on creative originality.' And it was like such a foreign concept to this suit, that I wrote most of that as dialogue for Taika Waititi."

Comment: I liked it, but honestly I thought there were a lot of obvious influences. Tron? The Truman Show, arguably.